# Correct method to build a multiple polynomial regression model

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, statsmodels, polynomials

I am using Statsmodels (Python) library to develop a multi-polynomial regression model. I have 6 variable columns and 1 target column.

One method for example in Statsmodel, there is an in-built function such as following (for power 2):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
pf = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2, include_bias=True)
X_poly = pf.fit_transform(X)
X_poly.shape
```

This automatically creates 36 variables (with my 6 input-variable from dataset).

At the same time, I also understand that I can also introduce polynomials for specific variables in my dataset. For example:

[image]

Question is, what is the right method to develop a polynomial regression model ? Is it better to use the first step via Statsmodel library, or the second step where I control polynomial powers for each variable ?

What are the differences between these two steps ?

Comment: Unless x has a good scaling, e.g. range -1 to 1, standard polynomials will be highly correlated. This makes the parameter estimates unreliable with higher order polynomials. Using the vander functions in numpy allows for scaling of exog. Also polynomials with formulas in `formulaic` orthogonalizes polynomials.

Comment: Does this mean it is better to go with the second approach that I mentioned in my post (or the first)? I've never used vander functions as well.

Comment: If you don't scale or transform x, then both will be numerically equivalent, and differ only in which fits better in your workflow or pipeline. If x is scaled or standardized, then you need to make sure that the data used in prediction is transformed in the same way as the estimation data.